# replace missing value in update left join statement

Tags: sql

I updated an existing table with the update left join statement as per the following:

```
UPDATE A
SET  A.SPSS_FieldForce = B.Remarks
FROM FBL1IN_working as A
left JOIN remarks_master_data as B 
    ON A.Vendor = B.Vendor_Code;
```

However, I need to replace the NULL values in the SPSS_FieldForce column with "Non SPSS / FFV' value. Currently, I am doing this with another statement as follows:

```
UPDATE
  FBL1IN_working
SET
  SPSS_FieldForce = 'Non SPSS/ FFV'
WHERE
  SPSS_FieldForce IS NULL;
```

This does the job, but I would like to combine this two different statement into one. I am sure that there is a way to replace the missing value on the first update left join statement, but I just have no clue how to get it done.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be sqlserver syntax, right ?
Then

```sql
UPDATE A 
SET A.SPSS_FieldForce = WHEN B.Vendor_Code IS NULL THEN 'Non SPSS / FFV' ELSE B.Remarks END
FROM FBL1IN_working as A 
     LEFT JOIN remarks_master_data as B ON A.Vendor = B.Vendor_Code;
```

Having B.Vendor_Code to be NULL means that the record is missing in your B table

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE w
    SET  SPSS_FieldForce = COALESCE(rmd.Remarks, 'Non SPSS/ FFV')
    FROM FBL1IN_working w LEFT JOIN
         remarks_master_data rmd
         ON w.Vendor = rmd.Vendor_Code;
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases so they are *meaningful* -- abbreviations for the table names.  Arbitrary letters make the query much harder to read.

Comment: COALESCE may not be the right solution : if there is a matching record in the ```remarks_master_data``` table  whose field ```Remarks``` is ```null```, you will write 'Non SPSS/ FFV' in your ```FBL1IN_working ``` table. If ```Remarks``` cannot be null then COALESCE is the right solution.

Comment: @OlivierDepriester . . . All `NULL` values are replaced in the second `UPDATE` in the question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : I saw it but I wondered if it could already be an error in the existing code ;) . Actually I do agree with you : if the expected result is as described in the question, COALESCE is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A SET
  A.SPSS_FieldForce = ISNULL( B.Remarks, 'Non SPSS/ FFV') 
FROM FBL1IN_working as A
left JOIN remarks_master_data as B ON A.Vendor = B.Vendor_Code;
```